# Give MapReduce parameters to hive query

Tags: hive, mapreduce

Is there any way to give map reduce parameters to hive query?
e.g. I am doing this, and it does not set that parameter in MR job.

```
hive (default)> set mapreduce.map.output.value.class=org.apache.orc.mapred.OrcValue;
hive (default)> select count(*) from myTable;
```

When I check the configuration of the MR job hive launches, the value of mapreduce.map.output.value.class was not org.apache.orc.mapred.OrcValue

Comment: Why do you try to tinker with Hive internals? If you really want to develop MR jobs yourself, don't use a query engine like Hive. If you want to use Hive, then leave the details to Apache committers...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the default Hive file format use `hive.default.fileformat` option, i.e.,

```
set hive.default.fileformat=orc;
```